# What is the use of jenkins with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What is the use of selenium webdriver with jenkins?

Is it ok to integrate jenkins in webdriver even if we are not using jenkins in project integration.

I directly get URL of website to automate, Is jenkins help anything me in webdriver?

Comment: This question is basically "why should I do continuous integration?"

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is a job scheduler. You can use jenkins to configure your tests to run on a schedule (eg: every hour, every day at noon, etc), or every time you check in code. Jenkins also has features to allow you to run jobs on multiple machines, set dependencies between jobs, and many other features.

WebDriver is a library for writing tests that exercise websites using a browser.

You can use jenkins to run your WebDriver-based tests if you want your tests to run automatically. If you run your tests by hand, jenkins doesn't help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins won't help you anything in automating Applications. Its continues integration tools which helps in running bunch of automated test case by scheduling different jobs.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver is an web automation API that helps to mimic user navigation.
Lets say you want to test search in google. You can use `WebDriver` to write a code which performs the below

1. Launch a google page
2. Identify search box on it and enter text into it
3. Click on search button

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
   driver.get("www.google.com");
   driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq").sendKeys("Selenium");
   driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb").click();
   ```

Once you have written above code, you may want to run it everyday, or every 5 hours. Instead of you going and manually running it. You can use Jenkins to schedule execution of your scripts as a maven build(`pom.xml`).

Also you can configure to run your functional test cases through Jenkins automatically after code is deployed and build successfully.